# Writing/Compiling inline equations within lists in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, compilation, r-markdown, markdown, inline

I am writing a document in RMarkdown. I need to insert equations, and, after that, inline explanations of what equation symbols mean. When I use a double dollar sign for the equations, I get what I expect:

```
$$ y_{i, j, k} = \mu + a_{k} + b_{j,k} + itype_{k} + etype_{i, j, k} + \epsilon_{i,j,k}$$

   $$ a_{k} \sim i.i.d. normal (0, \tau^2_1) $$
   $$  b_{j,k} \sim i.i.d. normal (0, \tau^2_2) $$
   $$  \epsilon_{i,j,k} \sim i.i.d. normal (0, \sigma^2) $$
```

[image]

However, when I try to describe inline elements of the equation, with a single dollar sign, it is not compiling properly (text is in Portuguese, but it should not matter, as the problem is with inline equations):

```
* $ a_{k} $ descreve a heterogeneidade entre as sessões;
* $ b_{j, k} $ descreve a heterogeneidade entre os individuos;
* $ \epsilon_{i,j,k} $ descreve a heterogeneidade entre os individuals;
```

This results in:

[image]

That is, formulas disappear when I try inline equations, and I get plain text. I updated my R and RStudio to the last stable version available yesterday. I am using Windows 10. I am trying to compile to Word. I also tried pdf, but it is not working either. I also tried to remove bullets-list markers, but still, did not work. Any guesses, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer to my own question. Sorry if I took anyone's time with it. If it is irrelevant or repeated, you may delete it. But anyway, I am going to share the solution here. All I needed to do was to remove blank spaces between dollar signs and math symbols within them (i.e. to trim the equation inside single dollar "$" signs). Trimming does not seem to be needed when I using double dollar signs ("$$") for centralized equations.

So, I solved the problem by putting:

```
sendo que: 
* $a_{k}$ descreve a heterogeneidade entre as sessões;
* $b_{j, k}$ descreve a heterogeneidade entre os individuos;
* $\epsilon_{i,j,k}$ descreve a heterogeneidade entre os individuals;
```

And then, I got:

[image]